# monodroid app not running on device

Tags: xamarin.android

visual studio 2010 and mono for android

softwares to develop a mono droid apk. 
Initially it create a project click the button, it can run successfuly on

emulator and i try to install it on android mobile (samsung galaxy y)for

that i search the (.apk file) in my project and it will locate it on

bin/debug/filname.apk.here in this bin folder i have 2 apk file

filename.apk and filename.signed.apk. I copied both apk file to my mobile

and try to install file name.apk but it failed to install and try to

install filename.signed.apk it will installed successfully, but when i try

to open it on mobile it will force close automatically.

on emulator my application working fine and also vs 2010 create two .apk file 1 is EventRegistraionApp-Signed.apk and another is EventRegistraionApp-Signed.apk ,only EventRegistraionApp-Signed.apk installed and it also install successfully on device but it giving exception which is shown below:-

```
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.DebugRuntime or Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_8! 
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4882)
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4485) 
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4425) 
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141) 
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.DebugRuntime or Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_8! 
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:30) 
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4879)
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): ... 12 more 
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Mono.Android.DebugRuntime 
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:226) 
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:21) 
 09-23 06:59:38.388: E/AndroidRuntime(863): ... 13 more
```

My problem is that after installation of apk to device it throwing exception of
Unable to find application Mono.Android.DebugRuntime or Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_8! but on emulator it is working fine

i am using monodroid 4.2.5 that is not showing evalution version

Answer (score 1):

You are using a very old version of Xamarin.Android, which I advise you to update, otherwise you are going to have a bad time. That being said you are deploying the application to your device in a wrong way.

You cannot take an .apk file created in debug mode and put on your phone if it does not have the mono runtime installed, which the deploy process does for you in Visual Studio. So instead grabbing the .apk file from the folder and manually installing it on the device, you need to press deploy or run in Visual Studio and select your device. 
Alternatively you can create the .apk file in Release mode, which will include the required mono stuff in the .apk file, however this way you will not be able to debug the application very well.

In order for your device to show up in the selection box, it needs to be prepared for development, which you can read more about here: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development

Comment: after connecting device using USB i deploy application in release mode    .it is created 4 files 1 is program debug database,2 is Appname.apk file,3 is Appname-signed.apk & 4 is .dll file.according to u can now i can installed  Appname-signed.apk on device

Comment: As Cheesebaron suggested, prepare your device for development and run the debug application on the device directly rather than the simulator.

Comment: Pressing deploy or run in Visual Studio will automatically install the APK on the device. No need to copy it manually.